# Python - Run process and wait for output

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to run a program, wait for it's output, send inputs to it and repeat until a condition.

All I could find was questions about waiting for a program to finish, which is NOT the case. The process will still be running, it just won't be giving any (new) outputs.

Program output is in stdout and in a log file, either can be used.
Using linux.

Code so far:

```
import subprocess

flag = True
vsim = subprocess.popen(['./run_vsim'], 
                        stdin=subprocess.pipe,
                        shell=true, 
                        cwd='path/to/program')
while flag:
    with open(log_file), 'r') as f:
        for l in f:
            if condition:
                break
    vsim.stdin.write(b'do something\n')
    vsim.stdin.flush()
vsim.stdin.write(b'do something else\n')
vsim.stdin.flush()
```

As is, the "do something" input is being sent multiple times even before the program finished starting up. Also, the log file is read before the program finishes running the command from the last while iteraction. That causes it to buffer the inputs, so I keeps executing the commands even after the condition as been met.

I could use `time.sleep` after each `stdin.write` but since the time needed to execute each command is variable, I would need to use times longer than necessary making the python script slower. Also, that's a dumb solution to this.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the subprocess print some kind of standard "done" message indicating it's finished processing? If so, you can probably use [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: Have you considered [threading, multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrency.html), or [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)?

Comment: Does the process dump data to the pipe or does it dribble it - when you get data how do you know you got all of it?  Are you saying that the process never terminates?

Comment: @Linuxios not that I know of, but I'll look into it.

Comment: @wwii I haven't but I will read the docs. I'm pretty sure it is multi-threading as is, if it wasn't the python script would wait for the child process to run (I could be wrong, never worked with threading before)

Comment: @wwii Not sure what you mean by "dribble". The process sends data to sdtdout (pipe) AND to a log file. So if it stop sending to stdout and the log file hasn't changed, the process is waiting for new input. With the current code you can say that the process never terminates (I waited for some minutes and it was still running, because of the buffered inputs). Maybe it will help if you think of it as a Python (or whatever) shell that is running a script that after doing some stuff waits for new input (which can be either "run more stuff" or "exit").

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python3, you can try updating your code to use `subprocess.run` instead. It should wait for your task to complete and return the output.

Comment: Like I said in the question, the task process is still running, it just doesn't give any new outputs since it's waiting for inputs.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019, you can use [subprocess.getstatusoutput()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.getstatusoutput) to run a process and wait for the output, i.e.:

```
import subprocess
args = "echo 'Sleep for 5 seconds' && sleep 5"
status_output = subprocess.getstatusoutput(args)
if status_output[0] == 0: # exitcode 0 means NO error
  print("Ok:", status_output[1])
else:
  print("Error:", status_output[1])
```

---

[Python Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/151d79fc99)

---

From python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.getstatusoutput):

`subprocess.getstatusoutput(_cmd_)`

Return `(exitcode, output)` of executing *cmd* in a shell.

Execute the string *cmd* in a shell with `Popen.check_output()` and return a 2-tuple `(exitcode, output)`. The locale encoding is used; see the notes on [Frequently Used Arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) for more details.

A trailing newline is stripped from the output. The exit code for the command can be interpreted as the return code of subprocess. Example:

```
>>> subprocess.getstatusoutput('ls /bin/ls')
(0, '/bin/ls')
>>> subprocess.getstatusoutput('cat /bin/junk')
(1, 'cat: /bin/junk: No such file or directory')
>>> subprocess.getstatusoutput('/bin/junk')
(127, 'sh: /bin/junk: not found')
>>> subprocess.getstatusoutput('/bin/kill $$')
(-15, '')
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use commands instead of subprocess. Here is an example with ls command:

```
import commands 
status_output = commands.getstatusoutput('ls ./')
print status_output[0] #this will print the return code (0 if everything is fine)
print status_output[1] #this will print the output (list the content of the current directory)
```

Comment: From the docs: 

Deprecated since version 2.6: The commands module has been removed in Python 3. Use the subprocess module instead. Question has python-3x tag

Comment: and it has python tag